# create-react-app json only loaded if I do a console.log

Tags: json, create-react-app

I'm using create-react-app and I am importing a json into a component.
When I dev, on yarn run start, everything is ok, as expected.

When I build and deploy in prod, only the second code works?
The first one gives me an error, telling me g is undefined.

```
import gr from "./test.json";

export const getJo = (g) => {
  return g.map(f => f.status);
}

getJo(gr)
```

By adding a console.log, this one works!

```
import gr from "./test.json";

export const getJo = (g) => {
  console.log(g);
  return g.map(f => f.status);
}

getJo(gr)
```

Comment: What is `g` in `getJo(g)`?. You are importing `gr`.

Comment: good catch, I wrote very simplified code, not really running one, so i didn't check if it was running.